# How can I add a 64 bit floating point number to an unsigned char array at specific indexes (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, c, char, stdstring

I need to add a 64 bit floating point number into an `unsigned char` array at specific indexes (ex. index `1` through `8`).

Example `unsigned char` array:

```
unsigned char msg[10] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

I want to add a floating point number like `0.084`, for example, which is represented as `1B2FDD240681B53F` in hex (little endian) to the unsigned char array at indexes `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` and leave indexes `0` and `9` unchanged.

So, I would like the unsigned char array, `msg`, to contain the following:

```
msg = {0x00, 0x1B, 0x2F, 0xDD, 0x24, 0x06, 0x81, 0xB5, 0x3F, 0x00}
```

So far I can get a `std::string` with the hexadecimal representation of the example floating point value `0.084` using the following code but I'm not sure how to add the string values back into the unsigned char array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    union udoub
    {
        double d;
        unsigned long long u;
    };

    double dVal = 0.084;
    udoub val;
    val.d = dVal;
    
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << val.u << std::endl;
    std::string strValHexString = ss.str();
    
    cout<< strValHexString << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`3fb5810624dd2f1b`

I tried using `std::copy` like in the example below to copy the values from the `std::string` to an `unsigned char` but it doesn't seem to do what I want:

```
unsigned char ucTmp[2];
std::copy(strValHexString.substr(0,2).begin(), strValHexString.substr(0,2).end(), ucTmp);
```

Looking for a C or C++ solution.

Comment: @Adrian Mole: why are you even thinking about considering anything other than Adrian Mole's solution?

Comment: @paulsm4 Why would OP even think about considering serialisation into byte array unless they are doing file storage or network communication. In those cases Adrian Mole's solution has the problem of incompatibility between systems of different endianness. It's fine when confined within one system though.

Comment: This is for network communication - I was originally thinking I would have to reverse the order, which I have done before using strings, but I believe both systems are little endian so the memcpy solution seems to work fine.

Comment: @user3716193 `the memcpy solution seems to work fine` It may seem so if you only test on one system or systems of same endianness. It won't work between systems of different endianness, which is typically a possibility that should be considered in network communication.

Comment: For a standalone application, worrying about "endianness" ... is stupid. For a *network message*, however, it's probably *ESSENTIAL*.  I frankly didn't notice the variable name was "msg"; nor did the OP explicitly say so in his post.  "Network messages" definitely call for a "more robust" solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting the component bytes into a hex string and then reading those back in again is a terrible waste of time and effort. Just use `std::memcpy()` (in C++) or `memcpy` (in C):

```cpp
    std::memcpy(&msg[1], &dVal, sizeof(dVal));
```

This will take care of any required pointer alignment issues. However, it will not do any 'interpretation' in terms of your endianness - but this shouldn't be a problem unless you're then transferring that byte array between different platforms.

Comment: For some reason I was stuck on thinking that I needed to add each byte separately to put them at the correct index in the array, my mistake. I definitely figured my string method was very inefficient. This works great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your example has undefined behaviour due to reading from an inactive member of a union. A well defined way to do the conversion to integer:

```
auto uVal = std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(dVal);
```

Now that you have the data in an integer, you can use bitwise operations to extract individual octets in specific positions:

```
msg[1] = (uVal >> 0x0 ) & 0xff;
msg[2] = (uVal >> 0x8 ) & 0xff;
msg[3] = (uVal >> 0x10) & 0xff;
msg[4] = (uVal >> 0x18) & 0xff;
msg[5] = (uVal >> 0x20) & 0xff;
...
```

This can be condensed into a loop.

Note that this works the same way regardless of endianness of the CPU. The resulting order in the array will always be little endian unlike in the direct `std::memcpy` approach which results in native endianness which is not necessarily little endian on all systems. However, if floating point and integers use different endianness, then the order won't be the same even with this approach.

Comment: std::bit_cast is not available to me, I am using C++ 11.

Comment: @user3716193 You can write your own `not_std::bit_cast` using `std::memcpy` and use that instead.

Comment: Ended up using std::memcpy. Upvoted this answer though - I think this was the direction I wanted to go in originally - being able to use the bitwise operations because I have used them before with integers, I just couldn't figure out how to do it with floating point numbers. Thanks.